# Facebook BlackBerry SDK

Tags: facebook, blackberry, sdk, social-networking

I want to implement facebook login and sharing in my blackberry app. Can you help me with a sample code of how to use it as I read the readme file it wasn't useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google with your title would have got you this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

Answer (score 2):

Download jar from here and add it to your project
http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

and write this code in to your project screen

```
ApplicationSettings sett = new ApplicationSettings("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html", 
        "facebooke  id", "secret key", Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS); 

facebook = Facebook.getInstance(sett);
user = facebook.getCurrentUser();

String result = user.publishPost(String pMessage, String pLink, 
        String pPictureurl, String pName, String pCaption, String pDescription, 
        String pSource);
```