# How to Integrate facebook with blackberry application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blackberry, twitter

This is first time I trying to integrate facebook in my application.

(I also want to integrate twitter also).

Can anyone tell me steps to integrate facebook with BB application.

I have app ID and Secrete ID.I dont know how to go further.

Please share code snippet or link or anything  related to facebook/twitter integration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374783/facebook-blackberry-sdk

Answer (score 2):

Download jar file from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/)

```
String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
String APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
String APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS;          

ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

try{
 User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
 String result = user.publishStatus("Hello world!");
 if ((result != null) && !result.trim().equals("")) {
    Dialog.inform("Publish Success.");
 } else {
    Dialog.inform("Publish Failed.");
 }

}catch(FacebookException fe){
  fe.printStackTrace();
}
```